# Ocultar un campo en una consulta de SQL

Tags: sql-server

Tengo una base de datos SQL Server 2016 y necesito ocultar el campo de contraseñas de una tabla, la idea es que con un `SELECT` solo pueda ser accesible por un usuario en específico, no tengo idea cómo hacerlo y solo he encontrado con encriptacion mediante un `INSERT`, pero no es lo que necesito.

```
CREATE TABLE usuarios (
    nombre VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    rut VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    pass VARCHAR(15)NOT NULL ,
    edad INT ,
    direccion VARCHAR(50) ,
    telefono VARCHAR(12),
    comuna VARCHAR(15),
    fecha_creacion DATETIME not null default getdate(),
    constraint pk_email primary key(email),
    constraint uq_rut unique(rut));
```

Espero que me puedan guiar con documentacion o código.

Comment: En realidad, esto no debería ser un problema si solo guardas un hash de la contraseña en tu tabla, que es la forma recomendada de hacerlo. De ser así, no importa que alguien acceda al campo, porque solo es un hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sí se puede, pero debe ser a través de la creación de un `Rol`

```
--Creación del usuario (en tu caso, es posible que esto ya exista, solo es un caso demostrativo)
CREATE USER SinPermisoContrasenaUser WITHOUT LOGIN;
GO 

--Creación del Rol
CREATE ROLE PermisosContrasenaRol;
GO 

--Asignación del usuario al Rol
EXEC sp_addrolemember @membername = 'SinPermisoContrasenaUser', @rolename = 'PermisosContrasenaRol';
GO 

--Quitar permisos de SELECT al Rol
DENY SELECT ON dbo.Users ([Password]) TO PermisosContrasenaRol;
```

Answer (score 1):

El enfoque que debes tomar es diferente.

La seguridad no se hace en la tabla en sí.

Se deben crear políticas de seguridad a nivel usuario. De ésta manera le puedes dar acceso a esa tabla a los usuarios que necesites.

Ahora, si necesitas que los demás usuarios también puedan ver datos de esa tabla pero que no puedan ver la columna contraseña puedes 1) cambiar la estructura de las tablas (poner los datos "visibles para todos" en una y los datos "privados" en otra tabla disponible para sólo unos cuantos) o 2) crear una vista que haga consulta a esa tabla a sólo las columnas que necesitas. Así le das permiso a los usuarios sólo a la vista, NO a la tabla.

Para lo que pides te recomiendo investigar los siguientes temas *logins*, *users*, *roles a nivel de base de datos*. Muy relacionado a éstos temas también están los *schemas* y *roles a nivel servidor*